# No se ejecuta botón en Android Studio Java App

Tags: java, android

Acabo de preparar una pequeña demo en Android Studio para aprender a manejar el Reproductor Multimedia. El caso es que tengo este código obtenido de tutoriales y documentación. Lo ejecuto en el emulador del Android Studio, pero no pasa absolutamente nada.

Estoy dándole vueltas y no encuentro la solución. ¿Alquilen sabe por qué?

Mi código Java:

```
package com.example.sonidos;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


public void Play (View view){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a01);
    mp.start();
}

}
```

Mi XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="Play"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Play"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.183" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

No se reproduce absolutamente nada. La aplicación se ejecuta pero

Comment: En dónde asignas el evento `click` al botón?

Comment: Mmmm veo un *onClick* pero creo que te confundiste, el *onClick* que tienes en el *ConstraintLayout* debe estar en el botón. ;)

Comment: android:onClick="Play", asigna la función al Botón

Comment: Puedes usar un onClickListener para el clic del botón pero como en este caso tu método recibe un parámetro ( public void Play (View view) ) entonces debes llamarlo desde el layout,  android:onClick="Play"

Comment: Debes agregar la línea android:onClick="Play" en tu <Button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu método esta definido de esta manera en la cual recibe como parámetro una vista:

```
public void Play (View view){
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a01);
    mp.start();
}
```

entonces no estas usando un listener y para llamar el método, en el botón debes usar la propiedad:

```
 android:onClick="Play"
```

para que llame el método "Play",  este sería el cambio:

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Play"

        android:onClick="Play"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.183" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, la llamada android:onClick="Play" está mal situada. Debería estar dentro del botón. Así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Play"
        android:onClick="Play"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.183" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```